# Approach and Code for o(log n) solution

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, number-theory

f(N) = 0^0 + 1^1 + 2^2 + 3^3 + 4^4 + ... + N^N.

I want to calculate (**f(N) mod M**).

These are the constraints.

- 1 ≤ N ≤ 10^9
- 1 ≤ M ≤ 10^3

Here is my code

```
test=int(input())
ans = 0

for cases in range(test):
    arr=[int(x) for x in input().split()]
    N=arr[0]
    mod=arr[1]

    #ret=sum([int(y**y) for y in range(N+1)])
    #ans=ret

    for i in range(1,N+1):
        ans = (ans + pow(i,i,mod))%mod
    print (ans)
```

I tried another approach but in vain.
Here is code for that

```
from functools import reduce
test=int(input())
answer=0
for cases in range(test):
    arr=[int(x) for x in input().split()]
    N=arr[0]
    mod=arr[1]

    answer = reduce(lambda K,N: x+pow(N,N), range(1,N+1)) % M

    print(answer)
```

Comment: what does `pow(i,i,mod)` do ?

Comment: You want to calculate `0^0 + 1^1 + ... + N^N` modulo `M`?

Comment: @alfasin pow(x, y[, z])
Return x to the power y; if z is present, return x to the power y, modulo z (computed more efficiently than pow(x, y) % z). The two-argument form pow(x, y) is equivalent to using the power operator: x**y.

Comment: Yes, @Patrick87.

Comment: But that's not what you describe you want to do... in the question you wrote that you want to sum all `0^0 + 1^1 + 2^2 + 3^3 + 4^4 + ... + N^N` and only then calculate the modulo (once). By doing `(ans + pow(i,i,mod))%mod` you take the modulo twice (which shouldn't matter but still redundant) and it means that you calc the modulo  for each and every item in the function

Comment: Well first of all 0^0 is indeterminate

Comment: @meowgoesthedog isn't it 1 ? ;)

Comment: @alfasin not when the base is 0. Google it.

Comment: @alfasin (a + b) % N = (a % N + b % N) % N.

Comment: @AkashdeepJassal true but what's the point in calculating the same thing over and over again if you can do it only once ???

Comment: @alfasin https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montgomery_modular_multiplication . I'm trying this approach. It leads to less time in computation.

Comment: @AkashdeepJassal if I understand correctly what's written in this link, it says exactly the opposite... calculating mod requires division which is very expensive on most hardware, so in practice you should try and minimize the number of "mods" your code is doing.

Comment: I tried reducing the number of "mods" but still it doesn't help.

Comment: @AkashdeepJassal reducing the number of mods doesn't change anything. The code looks fine to me, if you're getting an unexpected output, you should add to the question what are you using as an input, what's the output vs. expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Two suggestions:

1. Let `0^0 = 1` be what you use. This seems like the best guidance I have for how to handle that.
2. Compute `k^k` by multiplying and taking the modulus as you go.
3. Do an initial pass where all `k` (not exponents) are changed to `k mod M` before doing anything else.
4. While computing `(k mod M)^k`, if an intermediate result is one you've already visited, you can cut back on the number of iterations to continue by all but up to one additional cycle.

Example: let N = 5 and M = 3. We want to calculate 0^0 + 1^1 + 2^2 + 3^3 + 4^4 + 5^5 (mod 3).

First, we apply suggestion 3. Now we want to calculate 0^0 + 1^1 + 2^2 + 0^3 + 1^4 + 2^5 (mod 3).

Next, we begin evaluating and use suggestion 1 immediately to get 1 + 1 + 2^2 + 0^3 + 1^4 + 2^5 (mod 3). 2^2 is 4 = 1 (mod 3) of which we make a note (2^2 = 1 (mod 3)). Next, we find 0^1 = 0, 0^2 = 0 so we have a cycle of size 1 meaning no further multiplication is needed to tell 0^3 = 0 (mod 3). Note taken. Similar process for 1^4 (we tell on the second iteration that we have a cycle of size 1, so 1^4 is 1, which we note). Finally, we get 2^1 = 2 (mod 3), 2^2 = 1(mod 3), 2^3 = 2(mod 3), a cycle of length 2, so we can skip ahead an even number which exhausts 2^5 and without checking again we know that 2^5 = 2 (mod 3).

Our sum is now 1 + 1 + 1 + 0 + 1 + 2 (mod 3) = 2 + 1 + 0 + 1 + 2 (mod 3) = 0 + 0 + 1 + 2 (mod 3) = 0 + 1 + 2 (mod 3) = 1 + 2 (mod 3) = 0 (mod 3).

These rules will be helpful to you since your cases see N much larger than M. If this were reversed - if N were much smaller than M - you'd get no benefit from my method (and taking the modulus w.r.t. M would affect the outcome less).

Pseudocode:

```
Compute(N, M)
1. sum = 0
2. for i = 0 to N do
3.    term = SelfPower(i, M)
4.    sum = (sum + term) % M
5. return sum

SelfPower(k, M)
1. selfPower = 1
2. iterations = new HashTable
3. for i = 1 to k do
4.    selfPower = (selfPower * (k % M)) % M
5.    if iterations[selfPower] is defined
6.        i = k - (k - i) % (i - iterations[selfPower])
7.        clear out iterations
8.    else iterations[selfPower] = i
9. return selfPower
```

Example execution:

```
resul = Compute(5, 3)
    sum = 0
    i = 0
        term = SelfPower(0, 3)
            selfPower = 1
            iterations = []
            // does not enter loop
            return 1
        sum = (0 + 1) % 3 = 1
    i = 1
        term = SelfPower(1, 3)
            selfPower = 1
            iterations = []
            i = 1
                selfPower = (1 * 1 % 3) % 3 = 1
                iterations[1] is not defined
                    iterations[1] = 1
            return 1
        sum = (1 + 1) % 3 = 2
    i = 2
        term = SelfPower(2, 3)
            selfPower = 1
            iterations = []
            i = 1
                selfPower = (1 * 2 % 3) % 3 = 2
                iterations[2] is not defined
                    iterations[2] = 1
            i = 2
                selfPower = (2 * 2 % 3) % 3 = 1
                iterations[1] is not defined
                    iterations[1] = 2
            return 1
        sum = (2 + 1) % 3 = 0
    i = 3
        term = SelfPower(3, 3)
            selfPower = 1
            iterations = []
            i = 1
                selfPower = (1 * 3 % 0) % 3 = 0
                iterations[0] is not defined
                    iterations[0] = 1
            i = 2
                selfPower = (0 * 3 % 0) % 3 = 0
                iterations[0] is defined as 1
                    i = 3 - (3 - 2) % (2 - 1) = 3
                    iterations is blank
            return 0
        sum = (0 + 0) % 3 = 0
    i = 4
        term = SelfPower(4, 3)
            selfPower = 1
            iterations = []
            i = 1
                selfPower = (1 * 4 % 3) % 3 = 1
                iterations[1] is not defined
                    iterations[1] = 1
            i = 2
                selfPower = (1 * 4 % 3) % 3 = 1
                iterations[1] is defined as 1
                    i = 4 - (4 - 2) % (2 - 1) = 4
                    iterations is blank
            return 1
        sum = (0 + 1) % 3 = 1
    i = 5
        term = SelfPower(5, 3)
            selfPower = 1
            iterations = []
            i = 1
                selfPower = (1 * 5 % 3) % 3 = 2
                iterations[2] is not defined
                    iterations[2] = 1
            i = 2
                selfPower = (2 * 5 % 3) % 3 = 1
                iterations[1] is not defined
                    iterations[1] = 2
            i = 3
                selfPower = (1 * 5 % 3) % 3 = 2
                iterations[2] is defined as 1
                    i = 5 - (5 - 3) % (3 - 1) = 5
                    iterations is blank
            return 2
        sum = (1 + 2) % 3 = 0
    return 0
```

Comment: In the worst case, `M` is prime and you'll not hit a "cycle" until you compute `M` terms (then you are guaranteed to hit one by the Pigeonhole Principle). Still, that's a fair cost savings if `N >> M`. Another savings would be to intelligently factor like bases out in the case `N >> M` and share intermediate results with similar bases. Again, if `M >> N`, no significant tricks are possible since this devolves in the limit to having nothing to do with modulus.

Comment: Thank You. I'll implement your approach.

Answer (score 0):

why not just use simple recursion to find the recursive sum of the powers

```
def find_powersum(s):
    if s == 1 or s== 0:
        return 1
    else:
       return s*s + find_powersum(s-1)  

def find_mod (s, m):   
   print(find_powersum(s) % m)

find_mod(4, 4)
2
```

Comment: Simple recursion will give TLE. 1<=N<= 10^9

Comment: @ Akashdeep Jassal which IDE you are using or compiler

Comment: `m` doesn't necessarily equal to `n`