# Solving 1^1+2^2+3^3+...N^N

Tags: c++, algorithm, math

I want to calculate the sum of this expression for a large `N=10e9` and then modulo by a no `m<=1000`

`1^1+2^2+3^3+...+N^N`
I have tried this approach but still it is exceeding time i need a better approach help me.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>    
using namespace std;
    int expmod(int n, int p, int m) {
       if (p == 0) return 1;
       int nm = n % m;
       long long r = expmod(nm, p / 2, m);
       r = (r * r) % m;
       if (p % 2 == 0) return r;
       return (r * nm) % m;
    }

    int main(){

       long long n,m;
        cin>>n>>m;
        long long r = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
        r = (r + expmod(i, i, m)) % m;
        cout<<r+1<<endl;
}
```

Comment: @hnefatl As far as I can see, this code is copied verbatim from that answer.

Comment: I think the problem with your approach is in the "..and then..". I would do all the calculations modulo m to avoid overflow. In principle you dont need any intermediate result that is bigger than m

Comment: @hnefatl, that's not a duplicate, this question has other constraints and other solution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503007/sum-of-series-11-22-33-nn-mod-m tried the same approach but need a better approach

Comment: @DAle Where do the constraints differ? This question just seems to have slightly more relaxed versions of the other's constraints.

Comment: I give an alternative implementation here https://stackoverflow.com/a/45176437/847269 for the same question.

Comment: @hnefatl, `O(n*log(n))` solution is too slow for this constraints

Comment: @tobi303 the used approach has complexity O(n*log(n)) so its oblivious i am asking for better.

Comment: @tobi303, this question has `n <= 10^9`, "question that already has an answer" has `n <= 10^5`.

Comment: @DAle yeah saw it and deleted the comment. Nevertheless imho they are duplicates, or this question here should make it explicit that the solution given there isnt sufficient

Comment: btw the code seems to be an exact copy paste from an answer to the possible duplicate question. You should indicate where that code came from